# Combine two values to an object with a JOLT transformation

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I am pretty new to Jolt. The source format was generated from some software and does not have a good structure, so I would like to transform this. Each *text* ("First text" and "Second text") has an associated *link* (**"First text" -> "Link of first text"**; **"Second text" -> "Link of second text"**). How would you do such a transformation? Any help please?

Sample Input:

```json
{
  "flow": [
    "^First text",
    {
      "*": ".^.c-0"
    },
    "^Second text",
    {
      "*": ".^.c-1"
    },
    {
      "c-0": [
        {
          "->": "Link of first text"
        }
      ],
      "c-1": [
        {
          "->": "Link of second text"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "flow": {
    "links": [
      {
        "message": "^First text",
        "link": "Link of first text"
       },
      {
        "message": "^Second text",
        "link": "Link of second text"
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to use **shift** transformation.

One option is to create individual arrays(lists) within the first,
and then dissipate them to separate objects within the second transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "flow": {
        "*": {
          "*text": { // filter out by the key names ending with "text"
            "$": "&3.message" // go 3 levels up to grab the key name "flow"
          },
          "c*": { // filter out by the key names starting with "c"
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.link" // go 4 levels up to grab the key name "flow"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // stands for "flow"
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.links[&].&1" // &2 -> go 2 levels up to grab the key name "flow"
                                // &1 -> go 1 level up to grab the key names of the arrays
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]